# Learning Gittin a segulah for a good marriage?

Tags: marriage, torah-study, segulah, maseches-gitin

I have heard that there is a segulah to learn the halachos of gittin or gemarah gittin to ensure shalom bayis and a good marriage. Has anyone heard of such a thing? Do you have a source for this segulah?

Comment: I once learned Gitten and, well.... ;)

Comment: There's an old joke about why Gittin is before Kiddushin in Sha"S, but I haven't heard of a Segulah.

Comment: You're not gonna tell the joke?

Comment: @Gabi: Q: Why does Gittin come before Kiddushin in the order of the Talmud? A: Because G-d always precedes the  illness with the cure.

Comment: I was once at a wedding where the Chasan did a siyum on Bavli Gittin at his Tish. I found it was rather funny :)

Comment: Gabi, sorry, I didn't think it was appropriate on a serious question. But @Menachem beat me to it, anyway.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13383&pgnum=250